# How to get values out of a get_attribute_list

Tags: python

```
import requests

data = requests.get('https://...')

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
soup = BeautifulSoup(data.text, 'html.parser')

data1 = soup.find('div',{'id':'comparisonTabs1'})

comparisonTabs1 = data1.get_attribute_list('data-js-gtminfo')
```

Outcome

```
['{"Event":"productDetail","EventCategory":"Ecommerce","EventAction":"Product detail","EventLabel":"","Ecommerce":{"Detail":{"ActionField":{"List":"consument/vergelijker"},"Products":[{"Id":3211,"Name":"1 jaar Vast","Price":1600.45,"Brand":"Google","Position":1,"Category":"consument","Variant":"","List":"consument/vergelijker","Dimension10":222.0,"Dimension11":12,"Dimension12":"nee","Dimension13":6.9}]}}}']
```

I would like to get the values from `Position` (= `1`), `Brand` (= `Google`) and `Price` (= `1600.45`) with Selenium and Beautifulsoup. How do I get these values?

Would like to here suggestions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have extracted *JSON data*, so parse each element in the list as such:

```
import json

comparison_tab_data = json.loads(comparisonTabs1[0])
```

Now the three values are just key-value pairs in a nested structure:

```
>>> from pprint import pprint
>>> pprint(comparison_tab_data)
{'Ecommerce': {'Detail': {'ActionField': {'List': 'consument/vergelijker'},
                          'Products': [{'Brand': 'Google',
                                        'Category': 'consument',
                                        'Dimension10': 222.0,
                                        'Dimension11': 12,
                                        'Dimension12': 'nee',
                                        'Dimension13': 6.9,
                                        'Id': 3211,
                                        'List': 'consument/vergelijker',
                                        'Name': '1 jaar Vast',
                                        'Position': 1,
                                        'Price': 1600.45,
                                        'Variant': ''}]}},
 'Event': 'productDetail',
 'EventAction': 'Product detail',
 'EventCategory': 'Ecommerce',
 'EventLabel': ''}
```

so loop over the nested products list to extract the data for each entry:

```
for entry in comparison_tab_data['Ecommerce']['Detail']['Products']:
    print(entry['Position'], entry['Brand'], entry['Price'])
```

I'm not sure why you choose to use `data1.get_attribute_list()`; I would expect for `data-data-js-gtminfo` to only be a single string; just use [standard attribute access API](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#attributes):

```
comparison_tab_data = json.loads(data1['data-js-gtminfo'])
```

Comment: Thanks, Martijn. It is working. I am also using your suggestion on comparison_tab_data = json.loads(data1['data-js-gtminfo'])